# Flat file needs to be refreshed twice before updated information shows

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am writing a social media engine using Javascript and PHP, with flat files as my main information transfer tool. When my program adds to text files that are over a day old, they will not show up when requested by an AJAX program, until they are accessed directly by a URL and refreshed twice. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Please do not suggest the use of a database.

Comment: Make the browser not to cache them.

Comment: Could you please explain what that means and how to do it? I am completely new to Server Side Scripting.

Comment: Why are you accessing the files with AJAX? A better way would be to let a PHP script fetch the files and call the PHP script with AJAX. That way you have more control over what is and how it's sent to the client.

Comment: Would this problem not occur if used PHP to access the information? It seems I must refresh the page twice when using a browser to get the correct information.

Comment: So instead of using an AJAX request I should just use "file_get_contents()"?

Comment: Yes, or any other file function that fits the situation. You should read upon how web servers and clients (browsers) handle caching. HTML, CSS and TXT files are most likely served with a "cache this" header, where as PHP files being dynamic in nature are mostly served without cache controlling headers.

Comment: Sure enough, file_get_contents() works perfectly. I am definitely over using AJAX because I feel more comfortable with Javascript than with PHP, but that has to change. Thanks a lot for putting up with my noobiness.

Comment: Could you put your comment in the form of an answer to close the question properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason to why you need to access the flat files directly by URL and refresh twice is that your browser is caching them. Refreshing updates the browser's cache with the latest version.

When a web server is serving static content it tells the web browser to cache the content for quite a while since the content being static is unlikely to change for some time.

When a web server is serving dynamic content that almost always means that the content is going to change very fast and that it might be a bad idea to cache it.

Now the reason to why you shouldn't access your flat files directly with AJAX is not because of the cache issue (although it does resolve the issue) but because of **security**. What happens if you have some secret information in the file? Sure you can tell the browser not to fetch that part but the user still will have full access (by URL) to the file.

The same way you don't let the browser access your database you don't let the browser access  your flat files directly. This also means that they should be stored outside the document root or protected from public access by other means.